# Get data JSON in C# winform

Tags: c#, json, api, winforms

I want to get 2 data like "phone" and "username" from this URL: "http://localhost/api/basic.php?id={id}" in C#

I Use this code to get

```
string api = "http://localhost/api/basic.php?id=";
api += TxtID.Text;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(api);
myHttpWebRequest.Referer = "http://localhost/api/form.html";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern way (for .net 5 and 4.x) is:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;  // add the NuGet package

private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private async void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    MyClass data = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<MyClass>(api);
    ...
}
```

do not Dispose the HttpClient.

The package is not part of the default WinForms template, add `System.Net.Http.Json` from NuGet.

Comment: Make HttpClient static and it looks perfect

Comment: You can initialize a `static Lazy<HttpClient>`, if necessary. A default `HttpClientHandler` can be setup directly with a Lambda.

Comment: I got this Error: "Http" does not exist in System.Net!

Comment: You have to Add the System.Net.Http.Json nuget package. See the comment.

Comment: When you make the `HttpClient` *static*, you should also consider to make it *readonly*.